# If the strings of a language L can be effectively enumerated in lexicographic (i.e., alphabetic) order, which of the following statements is true?

Tags: automata

(A) L is Regular
(b) L is context free but not necessarily Regular
(c) L is recursive but not necessarily Regular
(d) L is recursively enumerable but not necessarily Recursive

I could only conclude that L is recursively enumerable from above statement but then why is it recursive ?

Comment: If we enumerate until we are "past" the word $w$, we know whether or not $w$ is in $L$.

Comment: I am unable to get in this that since all the strings are in lexicographical order so obviously all the words will be enumerated so then why will there exist any word which won't belong to the set